# how to uninstal a program when graphical mode can not load

Tags: grub2

I do not know what the grub really is!? But from some search I guess that is like widows safe mode. In windows safemode we can go and uninstall some programs which we have installed on windows. Is grub has this capability too? I installed a program last night and now some problems happen and my ubuntu can not load. I want to go grub and uninstall that in order to solve my problem. Please bring a example or say which commands i should type?
(Note : I installed one software and becpuse the lack of memory I can not load my ubuntu I wan to remove that to make my hard free)

Comment: Nope, [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) is a boot loader, and not a safe mode. What program have you installed? From where? What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRUB (GRand Unified Bootloader) is the bootloader used by Ubuntu. It's not the safe mode, but you can use it to enter Ubuntu's recovery mode.

To access the recovery root shell, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> during Ubuntu boot. It will reboot to the GRUB menu. Now follow these steps:

- Select *Ubuntu ... (Advanced Options)*
- Select the *root* entry (root console for recovery)
- Remount the system partition with R/W permission: `mount -o remount rw /`
- Now remove/purge yourprogram: `apt-get purge yourprogram && apt-get autoremove`
- Reboot: `reboot`

Comment: would you please say why we need to put "mount -o remount rw /" ? I asked a question about that that in http://askubuntu.com/questions/448231/usage-of-mount-o-remount-rw/448232?noredirect=1#448232 But still I do not know why we must write this command? is this belong to grup or what , also u can answer in the above link. thanks